# Hide a VC and segue from previous VC to new VC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I want to hide the ViewController on top of stack say VC . Then the VC just below this VC must be segue into new VC. And unHide the VC which was previously hidden , to the top of segue stack. How can I achieve this ??

ie , what I am trying to say is :

Segue Stack initial -> VC1 -> VC2

Hide VC2 then and segue from VC1 -> VC3

then show VC2 above it.

Final Segue Stack -> VC1 -> VC3 -> VC2

Comment: Please elaborate question by using VC1 and VC2 instead of only VC for two different view controller. People can't understand this.

Comment: @PaulMarshal Sorry, The question was elaborated with edit.

Comment: Do you want to do segue of VC3 from VC1 or VC2 ?

Comment: segue from VC1  -> VC3

Comment: Swift or Objective-C ? Please adjust your tags.

Comment: @Koen its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Whne in VC2, you can dismiss VC2 and push VC3 to stack like this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC3, animated: true)
}
```

And you can push VC2 when VC3 loads

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by manipulating **`navigationController.viewController`** property. See how..

For example you want to remove a ViewController from stack you do following..

```
NSMutableArray *newStack=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(id controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers){
    if(![controller isKindOfClass:[YourViewControllerToRemove class]]){
         [newStack addObject:controller];
    }
}
```

Finally assign the array like

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers=newStack;
```

The controller not in the array will be removed.

Now when you want to add just use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<YourViewController> animated:YES];
```

**Note: Check if the removed ViewController deallocs.**

Cheers.

Comment: there are lot of similar cases in my program I can't hardcode everything.

Comment: @ashinasok You don't need to hardcode.. You can make global function to perform similar operations, and just pass the ViewController as parameter on which the operation to be done..

Answer (score 0):

How about `UINavigationController`'s method, [setViewControllers(:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers)

```
let viewList: [UIViewController] = [V1, V2]
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewList, animated: true)
```

#### UPDATE

`V1, V2` are instances of class. They are created from storyboard or codes. If they are existed in the stack of `UINavigationController` already, they can be parsed from [viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers) property of `UINavigationController.`

```
let list = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
for v in list {
    // if v is V1 or V2 ....
}
```

I wrote a sample project and [put it on here: https://app.box.com/file/284901357701](https://app.box.com/file/284901357701).

Comment: They are `UIViewController`.

Comment: U mean is it the view controller class ??

Comment: You can use `setViewControllers(:animated:)` to manage the stack inside `UINavigationController`. For example, I have a stack with `[V1, V2, V3, V4]`, and I went back from `V4`, but I want the stack to be `[V1,V2]`, then I call `setViewControllers(:animated)` to be `[V1,V2]` when back from  `V4`.

Comment: my question how to get this v1,v2 ,v3 like is it view controller class?

Comment: I gave viewcontroller class but its not viewing.

Comment: I think it's not `class name`, it should be instance created from storyboard or codes.

Comment: I update my answer and put a sample project (SOUITest.zip) online. It works for me.

Comment: can u provide the link??